# Обновление базы из assets

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть приложение работающее с БД.. Сама база готовая и лежит в папке assets (сам пользователь туда ничего не вносит).

Изменила немного базу добавив пару таблиц.

Т.к. приложение уже установлено у пользователей возник вопрос как в таком случае обновить БД?

Самый простой способ что приходит на ум, удалить базу у пользователя и скопировать новую версию, но как это сделать?

Есть какие-то примеры?

Класс для БД

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static String DB_NAME = "database.db";

    private final Context myContext;

    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        createDatabaseAlt();
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public Cursor getSingleRecipe(long id) {
        return myDataBase.query(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECIPE, null, DBContract.Entry._ID + " = "
                + id, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getFavoritesRecipe() {
        return myDataBase.query(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECIPE, null, DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITE + " = 1",
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getCategory() {
        return myDataBase.query(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_CATEGORY, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getRECIPE(long categoryID) {
        return myDataBase.query(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECIPE, null, DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORYID + " = "
                + categoryID, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getWritableDatabase(); 
            myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        if (myDataBase.isOpen()){
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error(e + "Error copying database");
        }
    }

    public void createDatabaseAlt() {
        if (!checkDB()) {
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error(e + "Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private boolean checkDB() {
        File db = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
        if (db.exists()) return true;
        File dbdir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }


    public Cursor getAllData(String table_name) {
        myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
        return myDataBase.query(table_name, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }



    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Файлы в `assets` упаковываются на этапе сборки приложения в `apk` файл, т.е. вам нужно менять в `Android Studio` файлы БД, и выпускать обновление приложения, чтобы пользователи увидели изменения.

**UPD.**
В вашем случае нужно увеличить переменную `DB_VERSION`, а в методе `onUpgrade` удалить текущую БД и заново скопировать БД из `assets`.
В дальнейшем при обновлении БД нужно будет только увеличивать значение `DB_VERSION`

Comment: Вы не поняли меня.. Я обновила структуру БД.. И хочу понять как у пользователей обновить БД.. т.е. грохнуть старую базу и скопировать новую. грубо говоря как должен выглядеть метод onUpgrade для обновления БД?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна а мне кажется вы не поняли ответ, либо не все детали расписали в вопросе.

Comment: Я и хочу в студии обновить БД и чтобы она обновилась у пользователей при обновлении приложения.. Хотела бы пример где описано как в таком случае обновляется БД у пользователя.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна у вас база это файл, который вы прикладываете в `assets` - поменяете в студии, поменяется и у пользователей, что вы там собрались еще делать я не представляю.

Comment: Ну смотрите, если у пользователя уже установлено приложение, а я выпущу обновление с новой версией БД, но в методе onUpgrade не напишу обновления у пользователей ведь останется старая БД, соответственно те действия, которые я делаю с новой версией БД могут привести в ошибкам т.к. у пользователя не будет какой-то таблицы, или поля в старой БД

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна, если вы НЕ копируете БД из `assets` для дальнейшей с ней работы, то никаких действий вам делать не нужно. Если вы её копируете из `assets`, покажите класс работы с БД!

Comment: Я копирую БД из assets и дальше работаю с ней. Класс добавила в вопрос.. Вот нужно мне удалить у пользователя БД и скопировать новую версию.